# Self healing Spring Application: How do you reload a Spring bean if it crashes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a rest application that has a RootConfiguration class defined as:

```
public class RootContextConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer,
        SchedulingConfigurer
```

The RootContextConfiguation class has a few code beans such as:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public MyCustomBean myCustomBean() {
    MyCustomBean myCustomBean = new MyCustomBean();
    return myCustomBean;
}
```

The RootContextConfiguration is registered to my FrameworkBootstrap class which is defined as:

```
public class FrameworkBootstrap implements WebApplicationInitializer
```

The way I register the RootConfiguration is:

```
@Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

// AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext extends the AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext abstract class
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RootContextConfiguration.class);
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
```

Now, if a bean such as MyCustomBean crashes then the application will not
crash but that bean will not work. Since I use that on my service component which is called by my rest endpoint I have a service component
with a bad bean.

Is there a way to automatically recover from a crashed bean?

I am using Spring 4.2.3.RELEASE.

Basically I wonder if a bean has its scope as prototype but somehow it crashes on the ApplicationContext, can I reload the bean that crashes automatically? In other words, would that be any method that I could use to reload the ApplicationContext automatically in case something fails?

I would like to have a self healing application. Is it possible?

Thank you in advance,

C.

Comment: give a definition of "bean crash". Generally Spring wont help in recreating a bean in bad state.  However, if you have a way to identify a bean is in bad state, why not make a proxy as the bean to be constructed by spring, and in that proxy, you transparently create an obj to delegate the calls?

Comment: Well,  the last time the bean crashed was because ulimit on JVM due to a larger CopyuOnWriteArrayList datastructure. If there is a way to make sure the bean is valid or check it before it is consumed, that would be great. Maybe a Proxy Bean factory is the way to go but I need to see some examples. I though that bty using a scope prototype I would have a safer bean that just a singleton for the list.

Comment: But, I guess, following the documentation that going to a Bean Factory might be like doing the apps like in the old days. I guess the main goal is how do you reload the ApplicationContext, in this case the RootContextConfiguration class in case there is a runtime exception.

Comment: it is meaningless to discuss if you tell us clearly what is your meaning of "crashed bean", and how should we distinguish a "crashed bean" with normal ones

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make sense. Maybe read up on exceptions. We developers don't talk about a 'crash' just exceptions being thrown. The JVM should never 'crash'. Neither do instances of a class, they merely throw exceptions. In Spring, an exception if not caught, can be propagated back to a controller with `@ControllerAdvice` annotated on top and the corresponding exception can be put on one of its methods:`@ExceptionHandler(YourException.class) public String yourMethod()`. If you knew your class threw a specific exception, then you could catch it there, and then do whatever you want, return an error page to the view resolver, or create a new instance, and pass that wherever you want.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(DataAccessException.class)
    public String showDatabaseErrorPage()
    {
        return "dataBaseErrorPage";
    }
}
```

In general you want to make your application robust, it should not be possible to have beans in a 'crashed' state as you say. The application should show you what's wrong, not just crash.

**Edit**
I think there is just not enough information to answer this question, but I will do my best. Firstly ConcurrentHashMap should only be accessed by one thread. Make sure this is the case this could be your error. Maybe it's this library you speak of which has this map, and your not suppose to use this library in more than 1 thread, and you are, I have no idea.

Now for restarting that 'bean'. If your application is stateless except for any session beans, then you can use `HttpSession.invalidate()` in your `@ControllerAdvice` controller I believe (although I have never tried). Your application should be stateless except for session beans. Any other state should be kept in a database not the webapp itself. If you've done this the only thing you should need to do is end the session, as session beans can be the only component which can become 'corrupted', as that is the only one where the state is.

But if you have code which is making use of native libraries, and this is killing your app, there is no way to protect against this, all you could do is have 2 different processes which communicate with each other, and keep all native code in the one process, which if fails, you kill and restart. You can't really recover from. If you are generally storing anything other than a few integers representing database ids in your session, more than likely you are doing something wrong.

Recreating singleton beans is a nasty business, you would just be adding nastiness on top of you nastiness, and you wouldn't gain anything. You may as well just restart the whole app.

Comment: The application does not crash, I am handling exceptions all over and I do have a Exception handler as well:

@RestEndpointAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {
 @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
 public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handle(ConstraintViolationException e) {
  ErrorResponse errors = new ErrorResponse();
  for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
   ErrorItem error = new ErrorItem();
   error.setCode(violation.getMessageTemplate());
   error.setMessage(violation.getMessage());
   errors.addError(error);
  }
...

Comment: I also protecting the rest endpoints and all the services. Unfortunately, sometimes you can have a 3rd party library like ANTLR to throw some runtimeException although we try to get them on the logs and protect the system more.

Comment: But there are cases like the JVM issue, here is what I had last time:
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007f8159238120, pid=2477, tid=0x00007f8048fa4700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)

Comment: Register to memory mapping:

RAX={method} {0x00007f816cbc87c8} 'putIfAbsent' '(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;' in 'java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap'
RBX={method} {0x00007f816cbc87c8} 'putIfAbsent' '(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;' in 'java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap'

Comment: For these cases, or any surprises is why I really would like to be able to recover the application if just a piece of it, such as a bean, crashes.

Comment: Your very last comment demonstrates that you do not yet grasp the concept of an exception. 'Crash' doesn't mean anything to me, nor anything to anyone other than you.I don't know what it means I don't know what it means when you say a 'piece' of your application has 'crashed'.What's a piece?What's a crash?Why can't you just catch the exception.Is some ConcurrentHashMap throwing an exception all the time?Why did you post all this stuff that tell me nothing in many different comments?Why ask this question on SO?What's a crash?What's a piece? What's a unicorn? Maybe you should ask a philosopher.

Comment: I am not wasting my time with you, you definately needs some help. I have been doing Java since 1998, have 5 degrees from high institutions and I know what is an exception and a JVM instance that crashes. Looks like you have long ways to go in many areas. When an application cause the JVM to crash, it will log the error on the /tmp folder which is what I have written above. In any case, thanks for displaying and your knowledge both in technology as well as human philosophy. Good luck to you.